# Unique usernames?

Tags: support, new-users

Question: [Beamer TikZ generating two slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60812/beamer-tikz-generating-two-slides)

The questioner (apparently a new user) seems to have exactly the same username than me:

[image]

I just wonder how this is possible. Aren't usernames supposed to be unique?

Comment: It gets even worse: http://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=daniel, but the situation is similar for, Stefan, Marco, Tim, Josh, Tom, Martin, John, ...

Comment: @doncherry: Wow, that surely is disillusioning...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there is no requirement for unique user names: it is the ID which is unique. There is a presumption that people will avoid misleading names (this has come up before), but that is by convention not enforcement.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Hm... does the system at least warn if one chooses a display name that is already taken? This can become quite confusing...

Comment: @Daniel: Your gravatar icon is still unique and will be displayed beside your name in every question or answer. If this is not enough, then simply rename yourself to something more specific.

Comment: @Daniel: In reference to Joseph's answer that "this has come up before", see [User named Moderator](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2446/5764), where Moderator -> [Forgiver](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/users/9467/forgiver).